# Как нарисовать эллипс без черных границ

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Как можно дополнить код чтобы, он рисовал полностью белый круг, считая границы.

```
self.paint = QPainter(self)
self.paint.setBrush(QColor('#FFFFFF'))
self.paint.drawEllipse(e.pos, 10, 10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рисование границы выполняется пером, а закраска внутренностей замкнутой фигуры- кистью, так что нужно ещё установить перо такого же цвета

```
self.paint.setPen(QColor('#FFFFFF'))
```